# While using dynamic vhosts with dnsmasq, fixing phpmyadmin open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, vhosts

I'm running Kubuntu with apache and virtual hosts on my ~/server-dev/hosts/% thanks to dnsmasq. This time hopefully I'll find a way to stay in Linux. However, I installed phpmyadmin and trying to import an sql file yet it returns:

```
Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0
```

I have searched here and internet but I was insufficient to determine the reason. Will appreciate any help to keep me intact.

Comment: same error here. trying to import sql file in fresh installed phpmyadmin. (Mint 16)

Comment: could it be related to apache user? I changed it from www-data to my username on apache configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error message you can see that the path you upload the file to is not an allowed path.

Add the [upload path](http://php.net/upload_tmp_dir) to the [allowed paths](http://php.net/open_basedir) and you should be fine. Don't forget to restart the webserver / fcgi handler after you've changed your php.ini configuration.

Comment: Thanks I tried this already.
`open_basedir = /home/yahya/server-development/tmp/:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/` and `upload_tmp_dir = home/yahya/server-development/tmp/` This removes the error but still notification `No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration.` And sql.qz file is not damaged, finally upload limit is 32 MB while file is 1,8 MB.

Comment: Some hints: Start with small files. Create you own upload test script. Check that you prefix the paths with `/` (you didn't). Double check everything. If properly configured this just works. And it's no magic to properly configure something. So keep cool, just go through step by step and get it to work.